# Change Workbook Names to standard names in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a pretty long VBA code in Excel that references multiple workbooks. The issue I have is that the name of each workbook changes each month to reflect the new month/date, which then requires me to update the code with the new workbook name in order for it to work. Further, the change in name is not always standard across each month.

Is there any way I can, for purposes of the VBA code, rename each workbook that the code uses some standard name so that I do not need to change it each time? I know I can just create a new variable, call it "book1" and change its definition to reflect the workbook's new name, but everyone who will use the macro does not know how to use VBA and thus cannot go in each month and just change the name of the variable. Ideally I want VBA to always recognize the file, regardless of its real name, as another name, one that I set and does not change. I'm thinking there is some "technical name" that is attached to each file that does not change which I can use?

I have toyed with the idea of using dialogue boxes so the user can input the new name of the files, and thus have the code change accordingly, but would like to avoid that if possible.

This may or may not be possible, but thank you for your help nonetheless!

Comment: Do the filenames of the workbooks change as well?

Comment: Here are some suggestions on how to reference a workbook that might be helpful. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/

Comment: The `Workbooks.Open` method will allow the user to select which workbook(s) the macro will run against. You can use this method on a `Workbook` object variable, instead of a string or hard-coded item like `Workbooks("c:\files\August_Report.xlsx")` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possibilities:

- You could put in an extra sheet in the workbook, and in this sheet define that the file name is correct. Any Excel-User should be able to keep that info up. You could of course then check - before running your Long VBA code - if the files exist.
- If the file name for example is "filetobeused12_august2013" then you could search for the newest file that starts with "filetobeused12" and use this file in your code. This is the more complex approach for sure!

hope that helps,
max